Hard combinatorial optimization problems with super-exponential choice spaces
The following are examples of hard combinatorial optimization (CO) problems in which the choice space is exponentially large in the natural parameters of the problem:

Knapsack problem: choice is a set of items $\Rightarrow$ exponential in the # of items
Bin packing problem: choice is an assignment of items to bins $\Rightarrow$ exponential in the # of items
Metric k-center problem: choice is a set of facility locations $\Rightarrow$ exponential in the # of facility locations
Maximum diversity problem: choice is a set of points $\Rightarrow$ exponential in the # of points
Maximum independent set: choice is a set of vertices $\Rightarrow$ exponential in the # of vertices

The following are examples of hard CO problems in which the choice space is super-exponentially large in the natural parameters of the problem:

Traveling salesman problem (TSP): choice is a permutation of cities $\Rightarrow$ factorial in the # of cities
Vehicle routing problem: generalizes TSP

What are some other prominent examples of CO problems with super-exponential choice spaces that have been studied in the literature? Natural candidates are problems for which a choice is an ordered tuple of elements of some set.

Note that $n! \leq \exp(n \log n)$ so it's still exponential in the sense of $\exp(n^{O(1)})$, which is what you get in the definition of EXPTIME for instance. In the examples you give, the size of a solution is polynomial but not linear in the size of the input.

How about problems that ask for specific binary relations with minimal cost.
These problems are typically defined in terms of a finite non-empty set $V=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and a cost function $c:V^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that assigns a cost $c_{ij}$ to each pair $ij \in V^2$. The objective is to find a binary relation $A \in R \subseteq V^2$ minimizes the total costs where $R$ is a subset of binary relations (e.g. total orders, partial orders, equivalence relations):
$$\min_{A \in R} \sum_{ij \in A} c_{ij}$$
Here are a few examples from the literature:

Linear ordering problem (asks for a total order of minimum cost) has $n!$ solutions.
Partial ordering problem (asks for a partial order of minimum cost). The number of partial orders on $n$ elements is not known but it is greater than $n!$.
Clique partitioning problem (asks for an equivalence relation of minimum cost) has $B_n$ solutions where $B_n$ is the Bell number. This problem is equivalent to the correlation clustering problem.

All of these problems have in common that their feasible solutions are transitive. Another closely related problem is the maximum transitive subdigraph problem that, given a directed graph $D$, asks for a transitive subgraph of $D$ of maximum size that is transitive.
Further similar problems are the feedback arc set and maximum acyclic subdigraph problems. Here, given a directed graph, the objective is to find a an edge subset of minimum size whose removal makes the graph acyclic.
EDIT: Actually, these problems are not super-exponential in the input size. The input is a cost function that assigns a cost to each pair. So it is quadratic in the number $n$ of elements. And the number of feasible solutions is less than $2^{n^2}$.
